# Remove HTML tags from asp text box linked to confirm button extender without setting ValidateRequest="false"

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, validation

When a user inputs <> symbols in asp.net textbox control in a modal popup, a run time error is thrown on postback. I know in the past a lot of answers to this kind of problem is to set ValidateRequest="false", however I don't want to set that in fear of disabling security features that may block other attacks.

The user wants to be able to copy and paste email text that sometimes contains <> tags, however they don't mind if the tags are removed, they just want them to be removed automatically while copying and pasting and then submitting the form for server processing.

Can anyone provide an example of a solution for this kind of problem? If it cannot be done as the user likes what are some alternative solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So one of the hurdles I had was that modal pop up button that I wanted to fire the JS, was linked to an ajax confirm button extender that wasn't letting it fire.

I had to modify the behavior property of the confirm button extender by using an emca script, and include the JS function in that script. Lastly I do a check to make sure the extender is not null as depending on the situation I may or may not instantiate the control.

Here was my final solution:

After the Content tag in the beginning of the aspx page I put my script:

```
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(wireEvents);

    function wireEvents() {
        var behavior = $find("confirmBehavior");
        if (behavior !== null)
        { behavior.add_showing(formatText); }
    }

    function formatText() {
        var newValue = document.getElementById('<%=txtStatusComment.ClientID%>').value.replace(/[<>]+/g, "");
        document.getElementById('<%=txtStatusComment.ClientID%>').value = newValue;
    }
   </script>
```

Then for the buttons I did the following:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveStatus" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnSaveStatus_Click" Text="Save" OnClientClick ="formatText();" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelStatus" runat="server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnCancelStatus_Click" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick ="formatText();" />
                                <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnSaveStatus_ConfirmButtonExtender" BehaviorID="confirmBehavior" runat="server" DisplayModalPopupID="modalPopupExtender3" Enabled="true" TargetControlID="btnSaveStatus">
                                </cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue!